# converting curl command to golang conn.publish code

Tags: rest, go

I am trying to talk to server via Golang
and I am unable to get it to work:

However, the following CURL Command works:

"curl http://localhost:8888/auth"

I know the form is:

```
<subject> <payload length> "\r\n" <payload>
```

but everything I try fails.

The publish code is as follows:

```
// Publish takes a subject as an immutable string and payload inbytes,
// then sends the message to the server.

func (c *Client) Publish(subject string, payload []byte) error {
    c.Lock()
    pub := fmt.Sprintf("%s %d\r\n", subject, len(payload))
    _, err := c.w.WriteString(pub)

    if err == nil {
        _, err = c.w.Write(payload)
    }
    if err == nil {
        _, err = c.w.WriteString("\r\n")
    }
    if err == nil {
        err = c.w.Flush()
    }
    c.Unlock()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

I would appreciate any help that can be offered.

Comment: I'm assuming that is not the complete `curl` command since you have a payload? Can you post what the definition of `Client` is? what is `c.w`?

Comment: https://www.getpostman.com/ have a nice `code` feature.

You can export a request to several code snippets. Go is one of the options.

Comment: From what I see your `Publish` method only writes (to something, whatever `c.w` is), but doesn't send anything. On a side note your code can be improved, but that would be something for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Havelock As the code doesn't work at the moment (*"everything I try fails*"), it's off-topic on [CodeReview.SE].

Comment: @Zeta, sure... but is the above code snippet "everything" ? As I said I see nothing which would attempt sending anything over the network.

Comment: It would also be helpful to include the part with the definition of `Client`.

Comment: @Godfather It would be better if you add necessary information for your problem(i mean `Client` definition server implementation and so so stuffs)